# How to get CSV data as a string from GmailAttachment?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to grab gmail attachments that are CSV files then import them into a google sheet.

Here's where I'm stuck - turning the attachment into a string. I think I have a blob to which the method getContentAsString applies, but apparently I still have the type GmailAttachment because I'm getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot find function getContentAsString in object GmailAttachment.

here's the relevant code:

```
//************** get the attachments ***************************************  
  var attachments = [];
  var files = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
     attachments = messages[i].getAttachments();
     for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k = k+2) { //2 attachments per message, but I only want the 1st one
       j = k/2;
       files[j] = attachments[k].copyBlob();
       Logger.log('Message "%s" contains the attachment "%s" (%s bytes)',
                       messages[i].getSubject(), files[j].getName(), files[j].getSize());

     }
  }

  var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
    }
```

why is .copyBlob() not returning a blob, but in this case a GmailAttachemnt, and how can I fix it?

is the problem here:

```
       files[j] = attachments[k].copyBlob();
```

?

by the way I also tried getBlob() instead of copyBlob() and it returned a type error at this line above.

using copyBlob() I get the typeError at this line:

```
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The [copyBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment#copyBlob()) method of GmailAttachment class returns a Blob object. If you see the [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getDataAsString()) class, there is only getDataAsString() method to get the string value of the blob. Try changing the method to getDataAsString() and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to get the string value of a blob you should use: [getDataAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getDataAsString()) method in Blob class. The .getContentAsString() method is from the DocsList Service which is deprecated.

You could also use the getDataAsString() method from the [GmailAttachment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment) class itself. Hope that helps!